# mvc - post xml to another site (and redirect to it)

Tags: model-view-controller, http, asp.net-mvc-2

i am using mvc 2 and .net 3.5.

I have 2 mvc sites.

How can i post an xml message from an action/page in site 1 to a page in site 2?
And at the same time redirect the user from site 1 to the page in site 2.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to modify site 2 and add a controller action which would accept an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request (a.k.a. simple form POST):

```
<form action="http://site2.com/" method="POST">
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.XmlData) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Go to site 2" />
</form>
```

and on site 2 inside the newly created action which would serve as an entry point you could fetch the XML as a string and process it:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)] // <-- that's necessary as we are POSTing XML
public ActionResult Index(string xmlData)
{
    // Do something with the posted XML, and redirect or directly render a view
}
```

Comment: sorry about the delay in replying.